# Prove that $\sqrt{2} +\sqrt{n}$ is irrational

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Suppose $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{n}$ is rational,

so it can be represented like so: $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{n} = {x \over y}$

then  $\sqrt{2} = {{x \over y} - \sqrt{n}}$

so $\sqrt{2} = {x - y\sqrt{n}\over y}$

but $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, which leads to a contradiction.

Does this proof make sense?

edit: fixed some mistakes

Comment: What is the contradiction actually? More often than not $\sqrt{n}$ isn't rational either, so you haven't deduced an equation such that one side is rational and the other irrational.

Comment: Also you have sign error almost immediately.

Comment: Do reuse the ideas described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2533270/11619)! I like to think have a thread dedicated to the irrationalit of $\sqrt2+\sqrt3$, but it's too late an hour for me to search properly, so that other one has to do.

Answer (score 9):

At the last step in your proof the contradiction is not evident: why is ${x - y\sqrt{n}\over y}$ a rational number?

My hint: if $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{n}=r$ is a rational number then it is positive and by squaring we get
$$n=(\sqrt{n})^2=(r-\sqrt{2})^2=r^2-2r\sqrt{2}+2.$$
Any contradiction here?

Answer (score 4):

The polynomial $$\left(x^2-\left(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{n}\right)^2\right)
   \left(x^2-\left(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{n}\right)^2\right) = x^4-2(n+2)\,x^2+(n-2)^2$$
has $\sqrt2+\sqrt n$ as one of its roots. Any rational divisor would have to be an integer factor of $(n-2)^2$ by the [rational roots theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

But $\sqrt 2+\sqrt n$ is not an integer, indeed, if $\sqrt 2+\sqrt n=a\in\mathbb Z$, then $n=a^2+2-2a\sqrt 2$, implying that $2a\sqrt 2\in\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 3):

The sum or product of rational numbers is rational.

If $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt n$ is rational, then so is $\frac{2 - n}{\sqrt 2 + \sqrt n} = \sqrt 2 - \sqrt n$.

Then $\frac{\left(\sqrt 2 + \sqrt n\right) + \left(\sqrt 2 - \sqrt n\right)}{2} = \sqrt 2$ is rational.